# Simple User management example for Google App Engine?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

I am newbie in Google App Engine. While I was going through the tutorial, I found several things that we do in php-mysql is not available in GAE. For example in dataStore auto increment feature is not available. Also I am confused about session management in GAE. Over all I am confused and can not visualize the whole thing.

Please advise me a simple user management system with user registration, user login, user logout, session (create,manage,destroy) with data Store. Also please advise me where I can get simple but effective examples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22):

I tend to use my own user and session manangement

For my web handlers I will attach a decorator called `session` and one called `authorize`.  The `session` decorator will attach a session to every request, and the `authorize` decorator will make sure that the user is authorised.

(A word of caution, the authorize decorator is specific to how I develop my applications - the username being the first parameter in most requests).

So for example a web handler may look like:

```
class UserProfile(webapp.RequestHandler):
  @session
  @authorize
  def get(self, user):
     # Do some funky stuff
     # The session is attached to the self object.
     someObjectAttachedToSession = self.SessionObj.SomeStuff
     self.response.out.write("hello %s" % user)
```

In the above code, the `session` decorator attaches some session stuff that I need based on the cookies that are present on the request.  The `authorize` header will make sure that the user can only access the page if the session is the correct one.

The decorators code are below:

```
import functools
from model import Session
import logging

def authorize(redirectTo = "/"):
    def factory(method):
        'Ensures that when an auth cookie is presented to the request that is is valid'
        @functools.wraps(method)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):

            #Get the session parameters
            auth_id = self.request.cookies.get('auth_id', '')
            session_id = self.request.cookies.get('session_id', '')

            #Check the db for the session
            session = Session.GetSession(session_id, auth_id)           

            if session is None:
                self.redirect(redirectTo)
                return
            else:
                if session.settings is None:
                    self.redirect(redirectTo)
                    return

                username = session.settings.key().name()

                if len(args) > 0:               
                    if username != args[0]:
                        # The user is allowed to view this page.
                        self.redirect(redirectTo)
                        return

            result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return result
        return wrapper
    return factory

def session(method):
    'Ensures that the sessions object (if it exists) is attached to the request.'
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):

        #Get the session parameters
        auth_id = self.request.cookies.get('auth_id', '')
        session_id = self.request.cookies.get('session_id', '')

        #Check the db for the session
        session = Session.GetSession(session_id, auth_id)           

        if session is None:
            session = Session()
            session.session_id = Session.MakeId()
            session.auth_token = Session.MakeId()
            session.put()

        # Attach the session to the method
        self.SessionObj = session           

        #Call the handler.          
        result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'auth_id=%s; path=/; HttpOnly' % str(session.auth_token))
        self.response.headers.add_header('Set-Cookie', 'session_id=%s; path=/; HttpOnly' % str(session.session_id))

        return result
    return wrapper

def redirect(method, redirect = "/user/"):
    'When a known user is logged in redirect them to their home page'
    @functools.wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:    
            if self.SessionObj is not None:
                if self.SessionObj.settings is not None:
                    # Check that the session is correct
                    username = self.SessionObj.settings.key().name()

                    self.redirect(redirect + username)
                    return
        except:
            pass
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It makes sense. However I am troubled all day long if I will have to integrate django just for own user management. As far I get it , webapp only supports google users and all sort of support for that. Any help or advice on this? Can I simply do that without going for Django?

Comment: The above code isn't dependent on the Google Users, so you lose some ease of development but you get more control - none of the above requires Django... - All my user management is done without Googles User API (that is for twollo.com, ff.amplifeeder.com etc).  I only use Django for template rendering at the moment so there is no requirement for Django either.

Comment: is this still the preferred way for a customer user management? how is the Session - object implemented, in particular the MakeId() function?

Answer (score 6):

[Django](http://www.bubblefoundry.com/blog/2009/05/installing-the-google-app-engine-sdk-and-django-102/) is your best bet -- with the version I pointed you to, auth and sessions should both "just work" as per the Django docs.  [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/appengine_helper_for_django.html) gives simple instructions and example of how to proceed from there.

For Django sessions, see [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/); for Django auth, [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/).

Comment: Though I have used Django-on-AppEngine, I would not advocate ignoring appengines builtin auth over django. Any reason that you do? (Yes, I use Django outside of appengine too)

Comment: GAE's "builtin auth" only supports Google accounts, and in particular does not support "user registration", which the question very specifically requires (that's also why I didn't even bother suggesting OpenID this time -- last few times I did the askers saw it apparently as an attack on their desire to deal with their own user registration!-).

Comment: Users can register against the app specifically the first time they log in with their Google (or OpenId) credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You don't write user management and registration and all that, because you use Google's own authentication services. This is all included in the App Engine documentation.

Comment: So, my user have to use Google username? Can't they register only into my website? So, what will happen for user registration?