# How to process request with chain of webapp.RequestHandler

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, web-applications

GAE webapp allows to map single handler to a route:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
                                     ('/login', gae_handlers.UserLogin),
                                     ], debug=True)
```

Is there any way I can have a chain of request handlers?

I want to have handler which does authentication before all other handlers run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this either with decorators or with WSGI middleware.

There's a good example of using a decorator in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030293/simple-user-management-example-for-google-app-engine/1033333#1033333).  Nick Johnson's [AEoid](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/OpenID-on-App-Engine-made-easy-with-AEoid) project uses the middleware approach.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way

```
class ExtendedRequest(google.appengine.ext.webapp.WSGIApplication.REQUEST_CLASS):
    # I can basically do anything here
    def get_session_id(self):
        return self.cookies.get('session_id')

google.appengine.ext.webapp.WSGIApplication.REQUEST_CLASS = ExtendedRequest
```